# javascript Centipede, key press not working

Tags: javascript, keypress, processing.js

I built centipede in javascript from a Khan Academy tutorial. Then I figured out how to put it into a web browser. however, the key presses are not working. I have tried to change the keyCode values, and change some of the function definitions to "void" but nothing has worked. The app uses processing .js to work. Here is the section of js dealing with the keys:

```
var Player = function(x,y,size,speed){
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.size = size;
    this.speed = speed;

    this.update = function(){
        if(keys[LEFT]){
        this.x -= this.speed;
        }
        if(keys[RIGHT]){
        this.x += this.speed;
        } 
        if(keys[DOWN]){
        this.y += this.speed;
        }
        if(keys[UP]){
        this.y -= this.speed;
        }
        if(keys[76] && bulletDelay < 0){
        var b = new Bullet(this.x, this.y, 5,5);
        bullets.push(b);
        bulletDelay = 40;
        }


       if (this.x < 0){
         this.x = 0;
        }
       if (this.x > width){
         this.x = width;
       }
       if (this.y > 800){
         this.y = 800;
       }

   //This adjusts the max height the player can move up on y-axis. Adjust to make more like Atari version
   if (this.y < 100) {
    this.y = 100;
   }

   noStroke();
   fill(0,255,0);
    ellipse(this.x, this.y, this.size, this.size);
};
};
```

Comment: what does the browser developer console say?  Is it reporting any JS errors?

Comment: No errors displaying

Comment: Could you post more of the code or link to it?

Comment: I see that you sorted this out yourself, but in the future, please provide a [mcve]. The code you've provided doesn't tell us anything about the problem you're having. Try to provide a small example program that we can run to see the exact same thing as you.

Comment: Will do. Thank you

Answer (score -1):

The syntax

```
if(keys[LEFT])
```

should be

```
if(keyCode == LEFT)
```

See the [Processing.js keyCode reference](http://processingjs.org/reference/keyCode/) and [key](http://processingjs.org/reference/key/)

EDIT 1: For special keys (arrow, space), you should use `keyCode` instead of `key`.

Answer (score -1):

I sorted it out. The keyPress and keyRelease functions needed to be changed from

```
var keyPressed = function(){
```

to

```
void keyPressed() . . .
```

similar for the keyReleased function